# Running out of memory with MikTex

Tags: miktex, tikz-external, memory

I am attempting to build a number of figures with tikz...one keeps failing to build and the log file indicates I'm running out of memory.

I've used

```
initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex
initexmf --dump=pdflatex
```

To increase the available memory up to the point I think I can...the config file now reads

```
pool_size=40000000 
main_memory=50000000 
extra_mem_bot=40000000
```

And yet the log file tells me

```
43000001 words of memory out of 43000000
```

What's frustrating is that I have built this figure before on an older computer with less memory...it's cut and paste code....which makes me think maybe I've screwed something up that's letting something run away.

Here's code for the figure

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{singlecol-new}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\usepackage[external]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    external/prefix=\jobname-,
    external/safety=0mm,
    external/input source on error=false,
    }

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\tcbEXTERNALIZE
\tikzexternalize



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{extikzpicture}[runs=2]{fig7}
        \begin{axis}[
                height=8cm,
                width=8cm,
                xmin=0,
                xmax=10000,
                %legend style={draw=none},
                legend style={at={(0.9,0.4)}},
                xlabel = $\frac{V(A)}{Resource Cost}$ Ratio,
                ylabel = P(X),
                width=0.75\textwidth,
                y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=1,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    x tick label style={
         /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
        scaled ticks=false,
        ]
            \addplot+[black, mark=o,line join=round, mark repeat=1000] table[col sep=comma, y=Empirical, x=X]{CDFs.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize Empirical Data}}
            \addplot+[black, mark=x,line join=round, mark repeat=1000] table[col sep=comma, y=PT, x=X]{CDFs.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize Extended Pearson-Tukey}}
            \addplot+[black, mark=|,line join=round, mark repeat=1000] table[col sep=comma, y=SM, x=X]{CDFs.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize Extended Swanson-Megill}}
            \addplot+[black, mark=square,line join=round, mark repeat=1000] table[col sep=comma, y=BM, x=X]{CDFs.csv};
            \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize Bracket Median}}
        \end{axis}
    \end{extikzpicture}
    \caption{Elicited CDFs}
    \label{CDFGraph}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Obviously the data is important here, but I'm not sure how to include it.  It's 10,002 rows by 5 columns of floating point numbers to make 4 line graphs...it's honestly one of the simplest graphs in this paper...

The data file looks like

```
X   Empirical   PT  BM  SM
0   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
1   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
2   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
3   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
4   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
5   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
6   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
7   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
8   0   0.001   0.001   0.001
9   0   0.00101 0.001   0.001
10  0   0.00101 0.001   0.001
11  0   0.00101 0.001   0.001
12  0   0.00101 0.00101 0.00101

....
9990    1   1   1   1
9991    1   1   1   1
9992    1   1   1   1
9993    1   1   1   1
9994    1   1   1   1
9995    1   1   1   1
9996    1   1   1   1
9997    1   1   1   1
9998    1   1   1   1
9999    1   1   1   1
10000   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: One sure way to fix the problem is to do all your tikzpictures using standalone or externalize.  If you run out of memory for a single graph, you are using too many data points.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am running them externalized, and though there are a lot of points (10,000 per series) I have built this graph before...just not sure why it's running out of memory now.  Other charts that in the past gave me memory issues are working fine, but this one never caused a problem before...

Comment: The data file, cdfs.csv, is available at https://pastebin.com/u/jerH

Answer (score 1):

Having a need to bump memory in MiKTeX

I searched around and collected the following recommendations which allowed me to revisit and run this plot.

```
 > initexmf --edit-config-file=pdfLaTeX
```

In notepad change or if no prior value add the following lines

```
main_memory=12000000
extra_mem_bot=99999999
font_mem_size=3000000
```

save the file and back at prompt run

```
> initexmf --dump=pdflatex
```

If you get an error message you need to repeat and reduce values until --dump=pdflatex does not error (for speed use a "binary chop", half last difference)

previously the points required
2008247 words of memory out of  3000000 (default) for 25%
2938707 words of memory out of  3000000 (default) for 45%

However the final working log shows for the full 10000 points 100%
  793011 words of memory out of 12000000
approx. 10% of expected ! (guess it gets partially cleared during run time)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I uninstalled and then re-installed the pgf package and this issue disappeared.  Not sure if that counts as an "answer"...

Comment: No I tried un/install both pgf and pgfplots it did not make a jot of difference the only way it works for me is to have 25% of the .csv giving  2008247 words of memory out of 3000000 (the default) so could perhaps run say 4500 points max? update tried that and 4500 = 2938707 words of memory out of 3000000 so ok up to then but 5000 failed not sure if it would be much simpler to reduce data to every second entry? and bump memory a little